# Hovering data as a text, in inside container

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly.js, plotly-express

My query is that in my homepage, I want that only daily percent change and
market capitalisation seen on this child container. Hovering data should
only appear as a hover here but not as a printed text like daily percent change, market capitalisation. when I click on this child container,
complete hovering data must appear as a text.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash import dcc 

PATH = ['Sector','Symbol']
HOVER_DATA = ['Name','Country','Currency','Market Capitalization', 'Quarterly Earnings GrowthYOY','Quarterly Revenue GrowthYOY','dailyChange']
value_attribute = 'Market Capitalization']
Country_option = ["India","Australia","USA"]
Hover_Tmp = '<br>Name:%{customdata[0]}'+'<br>Country:%{customdata[1]}'+'<br>Currency:%{customdata[2]}'+'<br>Daily Change: %{customdata[14]}%'+'<br>Market Capitalization:%{value:0.3s}'+'<br>Most Recent Quarter:%{customdata[4]}' +'<br>PE Ratio:%{customdata[5]}%'+'<br>PEG Ratio:%{customdata[6]}%'+'<br>

color_scale = "#32a870", "#cc1819" 
input_date = '2022-10-21'

df = pd.read_csv(Data_source,Most Recent Quarter','PE Ratio%','PEG Ratio%','Earnings Share','Dividend Yield','Operating Margin TTM','Return OnAssets TTM','Return OnEquity TTM','Quarterly Earnings GrowthYOY','Quarterly Revenue GrowthYOY','dailyChange','date','Sector','Symbol','DailyChangeTreeMap', 'Condition','Description'])

df['Symbol'] = df['Symbol'].apply(lambda item: link_ref.format(item, item, "{}")) 

df = pd.DataFrame(df) 

def filter_df(input_date,country_name):
    input_date = datetime.strptime (str(input_date), '%Y-%m-%d')
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

    if country_name:
        df2 = df[(df['date'] == input_date) & (df['Country']==country_name)] 
    else:
        df2 = df
    return df2 

def create_dropdown(option, id_value):
    return html.Div(
        [dcc.Dropdown(id=id_value, options=option, value=option[0], style = {} ),],
    )


        html.Div(
            
        print("NOT EMPTY") 
        indicator = px.treemap(filtered_df,
                    color=COLOR,
                    color_continuous_scale=color_discrete_map,
                    # path = PATH, 
                    path = ['Sector','Symbol','dailyChange',],                     
                    maxdepth=3,
                    hover_data=HOVER_DATA, 
                   
                    custom_data=HOVER_DATA,
                    color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map)

        indicator.update_traces(textfont_size=22,)
```

[This is the screenshot of my homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEyaW.jpg)

[I don't want hovering data on this container as a text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8azK.jpg)

[I want this hovering data as a text in this inside container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOD1P.jpg)

Comment: can anyone answer this question??